# iOS what does performSelector:withObject:withObject: really do?

Tags: ios, performselector

What's different between selectors with same arguments type but different arguments sort?

I got these two selectors with same arguments type.

```
- (void)methodWithCallBack:(void(^)(void)) cb double:(double)value  {
  NSLog(@"%s %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, value);
  if (cb) {
      cb();
  }
}

- (void)methodWithDouble:(double)value callBack:(void(^)(void)) cb  {
  NSLog(@"%s %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, value);
  if (cb) {
      cb();
  }
}
```

But when performSelector:withObject:withObject: called with these selectors, I got different result.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodWithDouble:callBack:) withObject:@(2.5) withObject:[^(void){
    NSLog(@"Test Call Back Double");
} copy]];

[self performSelector:@selector(methodWithCallBack:double:) withObject:[^(void){
    NSLog(@"Test Call Back Double");
} copy] withObject:@(2.5)];
```

How does this happend? What does performSelector:withObject:withObject: really do?

Comment: What are the two different results you got with those two approach?

Comment: Neither of those methods can be used with `peformSelector:withObject:withObject:`. `peformSelector:withObject:withObject:` requires the method to have two parameters of object-pointer type. Both of these methods have only one parameter of object-pointer type (specifically, block-pointer) and one parameter of primitive `double` type. Wrapping it into a `NSNumber *` will not magically make it work with a method that takes `double` -- it would only work if the method actually took `NSNumber *`, which they don't.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do here, and why you are doing `performSelector` with a hard-coded selector, when you can just call it directly.

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea what @(2.5) is. `NSNumber` literal is @2.5. a double is non object and `NSNumber` is object. You should pass an `NSNumber`.

On a second note: I feel weird that Apple created `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`. A single "`withObject`" is suffice actually, you just pass an `NSArray` with objects you want to pass to that.

Eg.

```
NSNumber *var1 = @2.5;
NSString *yourMom = @"Sally";
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:var,yourMom,nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(goMethod:) withObject:params];
```